# I accidently ran 'sudo chmod -R 775 /' and it completely broke my OS/Shell

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, chmod

So I accidentally did `sudo chmod -R 775 /` when I meant to do `sudo chmod -R 775 ./`. I quickly realized and hit Ctrl^C, but not in time to save everything. I realize this is a really stupid mistake and all that but I'm aware of that and I would just like to fix my OS now.

Anyway, this completely broke my OS (Ubuntu 12.04). Currently, several functions of the shell, including tab completion prints the error

> bash: cannot create temp file for here

And running any bash command that I have tried on any file in my home (`/home/$USER`) folder crashes the terminal. Several other random things don't work around the OS now.

Comment: Fastest method to fix it: re-install from a live dvd WITHOUT formatting the partitions.

Comment: It would probably be much, much harder for you to try to restore your system than to just reinstall it at this point. I would suggest getting any data you have to another partition, and reinstalling. Reinstalling ubuntu is pretty easy if you have enough hard drive space to backup all your data onto a separate partition.

Comment: No, nothing has been annihilated. All content is still there, you will just have to recover it. You didn't do a `rm -rf /`.

Comment: @zwets Not so much about the files, all the important ones are backed up on git. But so many settings, programs, really fine tuned configurations, man this is going to be annoying to start from 0 again. Thanks though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Back-up important files (if you have any) after booting from a live-cd, then reinstall system. This is the only option that I know of.

Comment: Can't back anything up since all terminal functions are destroyed. :/

Comment: That's why you use the **Live-CD**. Insert ubuntu cd, start in live mode (boot from cd) and then mount your drive, recover any files you need to save. Then reinstall system.

Comment: This is a virtualbox VM, I have an ISO file for this OS. How do I do this on virtualbox?

Comment: The same way you would do with a regular PC. Mount the ISO and boot the VM, it will ask if you want to boot with the disk.